# How to make python and linux shell interaction？

Tags: python, shell

Now，here is an executable program that I run in a shell. But It needs parameter.How can I use python to pass parameter to the program in a shell. I know a tool in unix named 'expect' which can interact with existing software. I want to know if python can do the same thing！  My english is not good~sorry~

Comment: raise an example to make it clear

Answer (score 4):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. Basic example:

```
>>> import subprocess as sub
>>> sub.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Basically you can pass the command and its parameters as a list of strings.

---

**EDIT:** Reading again your question I wonder if [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/) is indeed what you want.